# How to get index of key that has a substring

Tags: node.js, arrays

I have a list that has values that look like this

```
[
  'Vehicle Type',
  'Body Type',
  'Engine Type',
  'Manufacture Dates\n                                 (First / Last)',
  'Fuel Consumption\n                                 (Urban / Extra Urban)',
  'Engine Capacity',
  'Transmission',
  'Acceleration',
  'Maximum Speed',
  'Total annual vehicle tax\n' +
    '                                 (2005 model and 1493 cc)',
  'Engine Type',
  'Engine Capacity',
  'Maximum Power',
  'Maximum Torque',
  'Acceleration',
  'Maximum Speed',
  'Fuel',
  "Urban\n                                 (100 km'de)",
  "Extra Urban\n                                 (100 km'de)",
  "Combined Fuel Consumption\n                                 (100 km'de)",
  'Fuel Capacity',
  'Seats',
  'Length',
  'Width',
  'Height',
  'Dry Weight',
  'Load Weight',
  'Baggage',
  'Tire Size'
]
```

I want to get index of Manufacturing Dates. Is there any short and concise way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const idx = arr.findIndex(element => element.startsWith('Manufacture Dates'));
```

Array.findIndex takes a function that returns true If the given element starts with Manufacture Dates.
It returns the Index of the first element where the function returns true.

See MDN dir details and more examples.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex